# mysql 5.6 FEDERATED table and mysql.servers correlation

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, federated-table

I have no expirence with FEDERATED tables in MySQL. I have database with FEDERATED tables defined and I'm wonder if this tables are used in current env (I have no access to application/developers to ask/check).

The mysql.servers table (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlservers-table/) is empty.
I wonder if connection info stored there is ephemeral or persitent after first connection to remote server/s.

My question is: if mysql.servers table is empty can I "safely" assume that this tables are not used by apps?

Answer (score 0):

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

> No data is stored on the local tables.

So if the original datatable has data the federated has too

Comment: And how this is related to my question? I'm asking about mysql.servers table :)

Comment: the table is always empty, you get data when you call it from the remote server, so you can't tell from that  if someone has used it, you can always enable logging, so yu know all querys that come your way.

Answer (score 0):

As I  had more time after work (and for proper rtfm:).

Simple test:

```
docker network create my

# start two server instances (one with federated engine enabled)
docker run --name my1 --network my -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --rm -d mysql:5.6
docker run --name my2 --network my -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --rm -d mysql:5.6 --federated

# wait for servers
MY="docker run --network my -e MYSQL_PWD=root -it --rm mysql:5.6 mysql" 
$MY -h my1 -e "show engines"
$MY -h my2 -e "show engines"

# Create databases
$MY -h my1 -e "create database my1"
$MY -h my2 -e "create database my2"

# Create sample table on my1 and put some data there
$MY -h my1 -e "create table my1.src (data varchar(10))"
$MY -h my1 -e "insert into my1.src values ('line 1')"
$MY -h my1 -e "insert into my1.src values ('line 2')"

# Create federated table on my2 db
$MY -h my2 -e "create table my2.data (data varchar(10)) engine=federated connection='mysql://root:root@my1/my1/src'"

# query my2.data table
$MY -h my2 -e "select * from my2.data"

# check mysql.servers table (should be empty)
$MY -h my2 -e "select * from mysql.servers"

# so mysql.servers is only populated with "create server" stament
$MY -h my2 -e "create server my1 foreign data wrapper mysql options (user 'root', host 'my1', port 3306, database 'my1');"
$MY -h my2 -e "select * from mysql.servers"

# cleanup
docker stop my1
docker stop my2
docker network rm my
```

Thank you @nbk for your answer.